# Passing an allocatable character to a subroutine with unlimited polymorphic dummy argument in Fortran

Tags: fortran, polymorphism, character, subroutine, fortran2003

I'm trying to write a routine that is able to convert a string into different kinds of data type, based on unlimited polymorphism. The idea is the user call this routine, passing the variable where it wants to store the data, and the routine to define the conversion based on the variable/argument type.

An excerpt of this routine is here:

```
subroutine GetAsScalar (this, value, status)
    !Arguments-------------------------------------------------------------
    class(TKeyword)                                 ::  this
    class(*)                                        ::  value
    logical, optional                               ::  status

    !Local-----------------------------------------------------------------
    integer                                         ::  stat        

    !----------------------------------------------------------------------  

    stat = 0

    select type (value)
    type is (REAL(real32))      !single precision
        read (this%fValue, *, IOSTAT = stat) value           
    type is (REAL(real64))      !double precision
        read (this%fValue, *, IOSTAT = stat) value
    type is (LOGICAL)
        read (this%fValue, *, IOSTAT = stat) value
    type is (INTEGER(int32))    !integer
        read (this%fValue, *, IOSTAT = stat) value
    type is (INTEGER(int64))    !long integer
        read (this%fValue, *, IOSTAT = stat) value
    type is (CHARACTER(*))
        value = this%fValue
    class default            
        this%Message = "Invalid data type"
        status = .false.
        return
    end select

    if (present (status)) then
        if (stat /= 0) then
            status = .false.
        else                    
            status = .true.
        endif
    endif

end subroutine GetAsScalar
```

"this%fValue" is a "character(len=:), allocatable" string.
When I try to use this routine passing an allocatable string, it exit with success, no error/exceptions raise:

```
character(len=:), allocatable :: value
call keyword%GetAsScalar(value)
```

But the string "value" is always empty.
Even inside the routine, after the assign "value = this%fValue", value is empty (len(value) is 0).

It seems that the compiler is unable to detected that the argument is of type character(len=:), allocatable, and so, is unable to assign the value to it.

Of course I have some alternatives, but the idea of being able to use a single rountine and without optional arguments for different kind of data is really nice.

I can use a user defined type that I create to handle strings, for example.

But I would like to know if this is the default behaviour in Fortran 2008.
And also, if there is a way to accomplish this, using this routine, with a single "class(*)" dummy argumment, to convert different types including the referred allocatable character. There is a way to force the allocation inside the routine, for example?

I'll appreciate your comments.
Cheers,
Eduardo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a select type (or associate) construct, the associate name **never** has the allocatable attribute (16.5.1.6p2), regardless of whether the select has that attribute.

In your case, the selector is also lacking that attribute - the `value` dummy argument is not declared to be allocatable.  You are not permitted to associate an unallocated actual argument with a non-optional non-allocatable dummy argument.  Beyond that, you are not permitted to use an unallocated selector in a select type or associate construct.

You need to allocate the `value` actual argument to some length before the call, the `value` associate name will then have that fixed length inside the select type construct.  Alternatively, wrap the allocatable character variable as a component in a derived type.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @IanH. I'll add the possibility to use a derived type I created (string), but will mantain the possibility to use the string, with the observation that is must be allocated before passed as argument to the routine.