# Deallocate in SELECT TYPE block

Tags: fortran, fortran2003

In the following example I try to deallocate an allocated field within the subroutine `deallocate_arbitrary`. This should work for unlimited polymorphic pointers in the end for multiple types, but in the example only a version for integer arrays is defined with `type is (integer)`.

```
module mymod
    IMPLICIT NONE

    contains

    subroutine deallocate_arbitrary(field)
        class(*), dimension(:), pointer, intent(inout) :: field
        logical :: deallocatable

        deallocatable = .false.

        select type(f => field)
        type is (integer)
            print *, 'deallocate_arbitrary :', f
            deallocate(f)
        end select
    end subroutine deallocate_arbitrary

end module mymod

program playground

    use mymod, only : deallocate_arbitrary

    IMPLICIT NONE

    integer, allocatable, target :: ints(:)
    class(*), dimension(:), pointer :: pints
    integer :: i

    ints = (/ (i, i = 1, 3) /)
    print*, 'ints: ', ints
    pints => ints
    call deallocate_arbitrary(pints)
    print *, 'ints2: ', ints

end program playground
```

Within the `SELECT TYPE` block `f` points to the unlimited polymorphic pointer `field`. My assumption is that `f` has the type of `integer` and it should be possible to deallocate the array `f` points to. Ifort 14 doesn't compile this example with error message:

```
error #6724: An allocate/deallocate object must have the ALLOCATABLE or POINTER attribute.
```

I assumed `f` would be a pointer and thus it could be deallocated. Is there a way to deallocate in such an arbitrary way or isn't that possible with Fortran 2003 standard?

Comment: The [answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27693626/1844448) says `the associate name never has the allocatable attribute`. My assumption is that `f` is a pointer. Then it would be (de)allocatable. Or is the assumption of `f` being a pointer wrong? Maybe the answer to above question is strongly related to the solution of this question, but I cannot see a duplicate.

Comment: `f` isn't a pointer: it's an associating name.  Possibly the [syntax used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31887568) is confusing.  Essentially, `f` isn't polymorphic, isn't allocatable and isn't a pointer.

Comment: That's clear, but `field` has `class(*), dimension(:), pointer, intent(inout)` attributes, so `f` would have `integer, dimension(:), pointer, intent(inout)` attributes. My question is, if `f` inherits the `pointer` attribute of `field` or not.

Comment: The attributes `f` "inherits" are very limited.  If you can find the Fortran 2008 standard (linked from [tag:fortran] information) then the section given in that answer tells you about the `pointer` attribute not being one of them.  `f` also isn't a dummy variable so doesn't have the `intent(inout)` attribute either.  `f` is more like `integer f(LBOUND(field,1):UBOUND(field,1))`.

Comment: `f` is not a variable and it does not inherit too much. It is all in the linked answer.